# R: Scale_y_continuous doesn't work with boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot2 in R, I make the following plot:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=type, y=v, group = v)) + 
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = type)) + scale_y_discrete(breaks=1:100)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Why is this? (Type is a categorical variable, v is a numerical variable, FWIW.)

Comment: Usually `group` is set to a categorical variable in `aes`, which creates the aesthetic mappings.  Perhaps this should be set to 'type' instead?  Also, can you describe what you are trying to do with `scale_y_discrete`?

Comment: some sample data might also help us help and desired output.

Comment: @SamThomas: D'oh, that was the error. Changed it to group = type and it works now. Thanks